# Stiefel-Whitney classes of 3-manifolds are trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Is there a simple way how to show that Stiefel-Whitney classes of a compact closed 3-manifold $M$ are zero? This is exercise 11-D in Milnors Characteristic classes. The available tools in the corresponding chapter are Poincare duality and the formula $w=Sq(v)$ where $v$ is the total [Wu class.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Wu_classes)

What have I tried:

By dimension argument, only $v_1\in H^1(M)$ can be nonzero, so $w_3=Sq^2(v_1)$ is zero. Further, $w_1=Sq^1(v_0)+Sq^0(v_1)=v_1$ and $w_2=Sq^1(v_1)=v_1\smile v_1$. So it is sufficient to show that $v_1=0$, or equivalently, that $Sq^1:H^2(M)\to H^3(M)$ is zero. But here I got stuck and don't see how to show this elementary. I believe that a full and general answer is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158821/relations-between-stiefel-whitney-classes) but can it be done more elementarty?

EDIT: Originally, I misread the assignment of Milnor's exercise: it asks to show that all Stiefel-Whitney **numbers** are zero, not classes. As I formulated it, it doesn't hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this is not true as stated because there exist nonorientable closed $3$-manifolds, for example $S^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$. Once you have orientability $w_1 = v_1 = 0$.

Comment: Are you sure? First, it would imply that there is a mistake in Milnor. Secondly, I thought that it is also implied by the fact that the unoriented [cobordism group is trivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism#Unoriented_cobordism) in dimension 3. Moreover, it seems to be implied by the mathoverflow link I included in the OP...

Comment: @Peter: it is not implied by that fact. $w_1$ being nonzero doesn't imply that the Stiefel-Whitney *numbers* are nonzero. My copy of Milnor-Stasheff only says "$3$-manifold"; it doesn't even say "closed," so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a standing assumption about orientability that wasn't made explicit or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, you are right about the SW numbers. Now I'm not sure. Is there a simple argument that $S^1\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ is not orientable and that $w_1\neq 0$?

Comment: Ah, the exercise reads "prove that all SW NUMBERS are zero", not "all SW classes". I misread the assignment, so stupid!

Comment: @Peter: ah, that explains things. In any case there are several ways to see that $S^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$ is not orientable. More generally, $M \times N$ is orientable iff $M$ and $N$ are orientable. One can also compute using the Kunneth formula that $H^3(S^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Q})$ vanishes.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

So clearly SW classes are not trivial for non-orientable manifolds as mentioned in the previous answer.

But if you are interested in some geometry you can try proving(!) or find a proof  of the fact that **orientable 3 manifolds are parallelizable**, which would then give an easy proof of vanishing of SW classes for *orientable* manifolds.

**EDIT**

This proof does not answer the question asked above for it uses SW classes heavily to prove parallelizability.

Suppose $ M $ is an oriented *Riemannian* 3 manifold, to prove M parallelizable it suffices to show that the frame bundle $ S(TM) $ is trivial. Now the frame bundle sits in a fiber bundle 
$$ \mathbb{RP} ^ 3 \cong SO(3) \rightarrow S(TM) \rightarrow M $$

Assume for now that $ S(TM) $ has a double cover $ \overline{S(TM)} $ which fits in a fiber bundle 
$$ S ^ 3 \rightarrow \overline{S(TM)} \rightarrow M $$
But then the fiber $ S ^ 3 $  is $ 2 $ connected and the base $ M $ can be given a CW structure with nothing higher than a 3 cell (say using nerve lemma) and it is an easy exercise to show that in this case $ \overline{S(TM)} $  has to have a section, which would imply ${S(TM)}$ has a section.

So why does $ \overline{S(TM)} $ exist? This is the same as asking if it is possible to put a spin structure on $ M $ which can be done thanks to its $ w_2 $ vanishing.

[Second Stiefel-Whitney Class of a 3 Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275370/second-stiefel-whitney-class-of-a-3-manifold)

[Spin manifold and the second Stiefel-Whitney class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808263/spin-manifold-and-the-second-stiefel-whitney-class)

Comment: This is, I think, strictly harder than just using Wu classes. What proof do you have in mind?

Comment: Interesting. Does it follow from some classification by a case-by-case analysis, or is there a main idea that can be summarized into a comment..?

Comment: ^^I agree this is a harder fact to prove, but I find this really interesting :) Also one cannot extend this to 7 manifolds (where I believe the SW numbers are also 0) :(. ^I'll edit the answer and write down a proof.

Comment: I remember once seeing a purely geometric proof which did not involve any bundle theory, but I am utterly unable to recall it :(  I would be really grateful if somebody writes down a geometric proof of parallelizability say using Heegard splitting or some surgery theory. Thanks.

Comment: "Because $M$ is orientable, $S(TM)$ is not orientable" -- why? It seems to me that if $M$ is paralllelizable, $S(TM)\simeq M\times SO(3)$ which is perfectly orientable..

Comment: You're right, let me remedy the answer. I was so hoping to avoid the SW classes. I haven't got my hands on any 3 manifolds book yet, for any geometric proof, I'll type one down soon as I find one.